# Show that a matrix is a multiple of the identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ three complex 2x2 matrices such that $$A^2=B^3=I\;(A\neq I\neq B),\quad ABA=B^{-1},\quad AC=CA,\quad BC=CB.$$

Show that $C=rI$ for some $r\in\mathbb{C}$.

I got the minimal polynomials of $A$ and $B$, but I can't go further to find the minimal polynomial of $C$. Any suggestion?

Comment: You could have $A=B=I$ and then $C$ could be any matrix.

Comment: It is my mistake; thanks for the remark! It is supposed that A and B are not the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ and $B$ are diagonalisable. As $A$ doesn't commute with $B$ then $A\ne\pm I$ 
so $A$ has eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$. It follows that the matrices commuting
with $A$ must have the form $rI+sA$. But this can only commute with $B$
if $s=0$. The only possible $C$ are of the form $rI$.

Comment: How did you deduce the form of $C=rI+sA$. I could do that with a bit of proof verification but is there any other way to "see" it?